# Is there a better way to group by a category, and then select values based on different column values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, grouping, data-preprocessing

I have an issue where I want to group by a date column, sort by a time column, and grab the resulting values in the values column.

The data that looks something like this

```
        time     value       date
0   12.850000   19.195359   08-22-2019
1   9.733333    13.519543   09-19-2019
2   14.083333   9.191413    08-26-2019
3   16.616667   18.346598   08-19-2019
...
```

Where every date can occur multiple times, recording values at different points
during the day.

I wanted to group by date, and extract the minimum and maximum values of those groupings so I did this:

```
dayMin = df.groupby('date').value.min()
```

which gives me a Series object that is fairly easy to manipulate. The issue
comes up when I want to group by 'date', sort by 'time', then grab the 'value'.

What I did was:

```
dayOpen = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda df: df[ df.time == df.time.min() ])['value']
```

which almost worked, resulting in a DataFrame of:

```
date             
08-19-2019  13344    17.573522
08-20-2019  12798    19.496609
08-21-2019  2009     20.033917
08-22-2019  5231     19.393700
08-23-2019  12848    17.784213
08-26-2019  417       9.717627
08-27-2019  6318      7.630234
```

I figured out how to clean up those nasty indexes to the left, name the column, and even concat with my dayMin Series to achieve my goal.

Ultimately my question is if there is a nicer way to perform these data manipulations that follow the general pattern of: "Group by column A, perform filtering or sorting operation on column B, grab resulting values from column C" for future applications.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the data frame before calling `groupby`:

```py
first_of_day = df.sort_values('time').groupby('date').head(1)
```

Comment: I now vaguely remember seeing groupby() preserves order, this is certainly a simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df.sort_values('time').groupby(['date'])['value'].agg([('Min' , 'min'), ('Max', 'max')])
```

For this small example:

[image]

Result df:

[image]

Comment: O thank you. I haven't seen an empty assign() what does that do in this situation?

Comment: I edited my solution and example, without the empty assign() part. It seems to be doing nothing.